# How to use Python Selenium via SSH

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, python-webbrowser

I'm trying to use Selenium via Python on a desktopless server. When I try to open chromium it says:

WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.35.528139 (47ead77cb35ad2a9a83248b292151462a66cd881),platform=Linux 4.15.0 x86_64)

What can I do to make it work, without using a desktop?

Thanks to all of you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm running selenium remotely without issues.

Are the versions of the browser and the chromedriver compatible? You can check this from the command line with `which chromium-browser` for instance.

Your driver should also be set to run without a window: `options.add_argument('--headless')`